# Rsyslog using else in config

Tags: logging, rsyslog

Hi I need have config file with:

```
if $FROMHOST-IP == '192.168.xx.xxx' then { action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/rsyslog/myHostName/device.log") }
else {*.* ?RemoteHost}
```

but rsyslog after restart give me this message:

```
Oct 13 12:12:40 syslog-new rsyslogd[29378]: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 118: syntax error on token 'else' [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
Oct 13 12:12:40 syslog-new rsyslogd[29378]: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
```

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RainerScript](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/control_structures.html) documentation on if..then..else is somewhat lacking in details, but in order to differentiate this use of `if` from the legacy filter syntax also beginning `if`, it seems you need to enclose the expression in `()`. Try

```
if ($FROMHOST-IP == '192.168.xx.xxx') then { action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/rsyslog/myHostName/device.log") }
else {*.* ?RemoteHost}
```